# Apache Camel Context Remove Route Definition methods

Tags: java, apache-camel

As part of my project requirement, I was going through the [Apache Camel Docs](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.11.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html) for removing Routes from the camel context before updating it.

Here I am confused with [removeRouteDefinition](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.11.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#removeRouteDefinition(org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition)) which removes a route definition from the CamelContext - stopping any previously running routes and [removeRoute](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.11.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#removeRoute(java.lang.String)), [stopRoute](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.11.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#stopRoute(java.lang.String)) which does the same work as former.

What exactly is the difference between these methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is, that `CamelContext#removeRouteDefinition` stops gracefully route, and then removes it from `Context`.

The method `CamelContext#removeRoute` can remove only stopped route. If you try to remove running route, the method returns false and nothing happens.

So these two snippets are equivalents:

**removeRouteDefinition**

```
getContext().removeRouteDefinition(getContext().getRouteDefinition("routeId"));
```

**removeRoute**

```
getContext().stopRoute("routeId");
getContext().removeRoute("routeId");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the documentation

```
void removeRouteDefinition(RouteDefinition routeDefinition)
```

takes a RouteDefinition object as the argument. Where as

```
boolean removeRoute(String routeId) throws Exception
```

takes a routeId.

Also another important thing is `removeRouteDefinition` is deprecated.

Comment: `CamelContext#removeRouteDefinition` was deprecated in some Camel versions only because it was moved to `ModelCamelContext#removeRouteDefinition`. While using Java DSL, you are almost certainly using `ModelCamelContext`, so the deprecation is not the issue IMHO. In actual camel versions, it is [undeprecated again](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.0/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#removeRouteDefinition-org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition-).